# Scrape href/URL

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

My code goes into a webpage which contains multiple entries, gets their URL and then puts them into a list.

Then it navigates through each list of URL 1 by 1, and then does a scape per presentation.

Right now I scrape each title of each presentation (you can see if you run the code), but within the title, there is another URL/href that I would want.

Is there a way to scrape this?

Thanks

```
from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import time
val=[]
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
for x in range (1,3):
    driver.get(f'https://www.abstractsonline.com/pp8/#!/9325/sessions/@sessiontype=Advances%20in%20Diagnostics%20and%20Therapeutics/{x}')
    time.sleep(9)
    page_source = driver.page_source
    eachrow = ["https://www.abstractsonline.com/pp8/#!/9325/session/" + x.get_attribute('data-id') for x in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="results"]/li//h1[@class="name"]')]
    for row in eachrow:
        val.append(row)
        print(row)

for b in val:
    driver.get(b)
    time.sleep(3)
    page_source1=driver.page_source
    soup=BeautifulSoup(page_source1,'html.parser')
    productlist=soup.find_all('a',class_='title color-primary')
    for item in productlist:
        presentationTitle=item.text.strip()
        print(presentationTitle)
```

Comment: Hey can you post the html of the element you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want some wait conditions in there and then to extract the href attribute for each presentation within a page

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
base = 'https://www.abstractsonline.com/pp8/#!/9325/session/'

for x in range (1, 3):
    driver.get(f'https://www.abstractsonline.com/pp8/#!/9325/sessions/@sessiontype=Advances%20in%20Diagnostics%20and%20Therapeutics/{x}')
    links = [base + i.get_attribute('data-id') for i in WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "li .name")))]
    
    for link in links:
        driver.get(link)
        print(WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "spnSessionTitle"))).text)
        for presentation in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.title'):
            print(presentation.text.strip())
            print('https://www.abstractsonline.com/pp8' + presentation.get_attribute('href'))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
links = driver.find_elements_by_partial_link_text('https://yourlinks.com/?action=')

for link in links:
    print(link.get_attribute("href"))
```